# Passing multiple parameters to Django URL - unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, django, django-views

How to can I address this `NoReverseMatch` error?

Context

I want to document this question as much as possible in order to be able to detail the origin of the problem.

I have a model named `LodgingOffer`, to create a lodging offer and have the detail their information

```
class LodgingOffer(models.Model):

    # Foreign Key to my User model      
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    ad_title = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False,
        max_length=255, verbose_name='Título de la oferta')

    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    # ... Another fields ...

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.ad_title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('host:detail', kwargs = {'slug' : self.slug })

# I assign slug to offer based in ad_title field,checking if slug exist
def create_slug(instance, new_slug=None):
    slug = slugify(instance.ad_title)
    if new_slug is not None:
        slug = new_slug
    qs = LodgingOffer.objects.filter(slug=slug).order_by("-id")
    exists = qs.exists()
    if exists:
        new_slug = "%s-%s" % (slug, qs.first().id)
        return create_slug(instance, new_slug=new_slug)
    return slug

# Brefore to save, assign slug to offer created above.
def pre_save_article_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug = create_slug(instance)

pre_save.connect(pre_save_article_receiver, sender=LodgingOffer)
```

---

For this model, I have a  DetailView named `HostingOfferDetailView` .

An important objective I want to pursue and for which I ask this question is that in the detail view of an `LodgingOffer` object, I should be able to contact the owner of that offer (object `LodgingOffer` - user who created it -) so that another interested user can apply to it.

I would like that in the detail view for the `LodgingOffer` object be able to contact the offer owner (object `LodgingOffer` - user who created it -) so others users interested could apply to it

For this purpose, I have `contact_owner_offer()` function, is where I send an email to the owner of this offer.

I'm doing all using the `HostingOfferDetailView` detail view like this:

```
class HostingOfferDetailView(DetailView):
    model = LodgingOffer
    template_name = 'lodgingoffer_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'lodgingofferdetail'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HostingOfferDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = self.request.user

        # Get the related data offer
        #lodging_offer_owner = self.get_object()
        lodging_offer_owner_full_name = self.get_object().created_by.get_long_name()

        lodging_offer_owner_email = self.get_object().created_by.email

        lodging_offer_title = self.get_object().ad_title
        user_interested_email = user.email
        user_interested_full_name = user.get_long_name()

        # Send to context email of owner offer and user interested in offer
        context['user_interested_email'] = user_interested_email
        context['lodging_offer_owner_email'] = lodging_offer_owner_email

        # Send the data (lodging_offer_owner_email
        # user_interested_email and lodging_offer_title) presented 
        # above to the contact_owner_offer function
        contact_owner_offer(self.request, lodging_offer_owner_email, user_interested_email, lodging_offer_title)

        return context
```

My `contact_owner_offer()` function receives these offer parameters and sends an email to the owner of the offer or the publisher, as follows:

```
def contact_owner_offer(request, lodging_offer_owner_email, user_interested_email, lodging_offer_title):
    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated:
        # print('Send email')
        mail_subject = 'Interest in your offer'

        context = {
            'lodging_offer_owner_email': lodging_offer_owner_email,
            # User owner offer - TO send email message

            'offer': lodging_offer_title,
            # offer for which a user asks 

            'user_interested_email': user_interested_email,
            # Interested user offer

            'domain': settings.SITE_URL,
            'request': request
        }

        message = render_to_string('contact_user_own_offer.html', context)
        #to_email = lodging_offer_owner.email,

        send_mail(mail_subject, message, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
                  [lodging_offer_owner_email], fail_silently=True)
```

I have done this as a test and so far everything is as I wanted, and the result is that when I enter the URL of a detailed offer object `LodgingOffer`, an email is sent to the owner of that offer.

What I would like that the offer detail template has a button with contains **"Contact the owner of the offer"** and when any user who presses it send an email to the owner of the offer.

To do this I defined a URL for `contact_owner_offer()` function and it has a link on the `href` attribute of a button in my template.

The URL, (according to my understanding and this is where the doubt and the reason for my question resides) I have defined it according to the number of parameters that the `contact_owner_offer()` function receives.

This means my URL must receive:

- The offer owner's email address
- The e-mail address of the user interested in the offer
- The title of the offer, **although for this I'm
  sending you the slug of that title, I don't know if that's correct**.

So, according to the above, I've created this URL:

```
url(r'^contact-to-owner/(?P<email>[\w.@+-]+)/from/'
        r'(?P<interested_email>[\w.@+-]+)/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$',
        contact_owner_offer, name='contact_owner_offer'),
```

Then, in my template, I generate an html button where I call this URL sending them their respective parameters that expect:

```
<div class="contact">
    <a class="contact-button" href="{% url 'host:contact_owner_offer' email=lodging_offer_owner_email interested_email=user_interested_email slug=lodgingofferdetail.slug %}">
        <img src="{% static 'img/icons/contact.svg' %}" alt="">
        <span>Contact owner offer</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

What happens to me is that when I enter the offer detail template and click on the **Contact owner offer** reference button immediately above, I get the following error message:

```
 TypeError: contact_owner_offer() got an unexpected keyword argument 'email'
[10/Oct/2017 01:04:06] "GET /host/contact-to-owner/botibagl@gmail.com/from/ces@ces.edu.co/apartacho/ HTTP/1.1" 500 77979
```

My traceback is here

```
Traceback:

File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/hostayni/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  42.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/hostayni/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/hostayni/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /host/contact-to-owner/botibagl@gmail.com/from/botibagl@gmail.com/apartacho/
Exception Value: contact_owner_offer() got an unexpected keyword argument 'email'
```

What I don't understand, is because it tells me that my URL doesn't wait for an argument called `email` which is where I pass the parameter `email=lodging_offer_owner_owner_email` through the button in the template.

I appreciate any guidance
Best Regards

---

**UPDATE**

According to the [@RajKris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8482471/rajkris) and [@Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) recommendations I've changed slightly my URL regex, specifying the name of the keyword argument which I am passing. The URL stay of this way:

```
url(r'^contact-to-owner/(?P<lodging_offer_owner_email>[\w.@+-]+)/from/'
        r'(?P<interested_email>[\w.@+-]+)/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$',
        contact_owner_offer,
        name='contact_owner_offer'
    ),
```

This mean, I am naming the url parameters of the same way in which I've named the parameters that `contact_owner_offer()` receive.

And when I  enter the offer detail template and click on the **Contact owner offer** reference button I get the `NoReverseMatch` error

```
Template error:
In template /home/bgarcial/workspace/hostayni_platform/hosts/templates/lodgingoffer_detail.html, error at line 193
   Reverse for 'contact_owner_offer' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'email': 'botibagl@gmail.com', 'interested_email': 'botibagl@gmail.com', 'slug': 'apartacho'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['host/contact-to-owner/(?P<lodging_offer_owner_email>[\\w.@+-]+)/from/(?P<interested_email>[\\w.@+-]+)/(?P<slug>[\\w-]+)/$']   183 :                                </tr>
   184 :                                <tr>
   185 :                                    <td>{{ lodgingofferdetail.room_value }}</td>
   186 :                                    <td>{{ lodgingofferdetail.additional_description }}</td>
   187 :                                    <td>{{ lodgingofferdetail.lodging_offer_owner_email }}</td>
   188 :                                </tr>
   189 :                            </tbody>
   190 :                        </table>
   191 :                    </div>
   192 :                    <div class="contact">
   193 :                        <a class="contact-button" href=" {% url 'host:contact_owner_offer' email=lodging_offer_owner_email interested_email=user_interested_email slug=lodgingofferdetail.slug %} ">
   194 :                            <img src="{% static 'img/icons/contact.svg' %}" alt="">
   195 :                            <span>Contactar</span>
   196 :                        </a>
   197 :                    </div>
```

The general traceback is here:

```
File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/hostayni/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  392.             (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /host/lodging-offer/apartacho/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'contact_owner_offer' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'email': 'botibagl@gmail.com', 'interested_email': 'botibagl@gmail.com', 'slug': 'apartacho'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['host/contact-to-owner/(?P<lodging_offer_owner_email>[\\w.@+-]+)/from/(?P<interested_email>[\\w.@+-]+)/(?P<slug>[\\w-]+)/$']
```

How to can I address this `NoReverseMatch` error?

Comment: Are you trying to call another view from one view ? Or just want to call a function ? If you just want to call a function, don't have to list it in ulrs.

Comment: Firstly, doing any action like sending emails on GET is a very bad idea. Secondly, the URL you have posted here **would not** give this error; instead you would get a ReverseMatchError, because you are passing keyword args to the `{% url %}` tag. Finally, don't post a screenshot of an error; click that link that says "Switch to copy-and-paste view' and post the resulting text *as text*.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks for the tips. The email sent on DetailView is just as a test, this call to the `contact_owner_offer()` function inside `HostingOfferDetailView` won't be included in the end. I've post my traceback, it's true I am passing keyword args in the `{% url %}` tag, but I don't know the reason which I get the same error `Exception Value: contact_owner_offer() got an unexpected keyword argument 'email'`

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal I am calling a function based view (`contact_owner_offer()`) inside my `HostingOfferDetailView` class based view. I did this, because the idea is reach to `contact_owner_offer()` by calling it by means of the `{% url %}` tag in my template, and receive these parameters which I am passing

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've changed  slightly my URL regex, specifying the name of the keyword argument which I am passing, and I get the ReverseMatchError that you specify me. I would like if you can check this scenarie please

Answer (score 1):

In the URL regex you have to specify, name of the kyword arg you're passing:

```
url(r'^contact-to-owner/(?P<email1>[\w.@+-]+)/from/' r'(?P<email1>[\w.@+-]+)/(?P<email3>[\w-]+)/$', contact_owner_offer, name='contact_owner_offer'),
```

This is referred here:

[Django Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#named-groups)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I still don't finish of understand the named groups parameters in URL. I've changed  slightly my URL regex, specifying the name of the keyword argument which I am passing, and I get the ReverseMatchError, an error different. I know that the problem is my URL, when I define it. ?

Comment: Can you check my **update** to my original question please?

Answer (score 1):

Why not using simple url with get params?

e.g. "contact-to-owner/?owner-email=xxx&user-email=xxx&title=xxx"